# dont know how to make a proper mixin for background

Tags: html, css, sass

I am using Scss for my website.I am trying to make my code easier to read so I thought about building a mixin for my background property.I haven't used a mixin before tho..
 I want to create a mixin with these properties:
        background: #6441A5;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #6441A5 , #2a0845);
        background: linear-gradient(to left, #6441A5 , #2a0845);

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you need is:

```
@mixin background_mixin($bg) {
    background: $bg
}
```

And when you need to make background eg #6441A5:

```
@include background_mixin(#6441A5);
```

Mixin is like a function (in our case named background_mixin) and you give it a parameter (in our case named $bg). Then in the block of code you want to use it you make an @include with the name of the mixin and the value that you want the parameter to get.

More information here:

- http://sass-lang.com/guide
- https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-the-mixin-directive/